# GLib Hash Table Lookup Failure

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to learn how to use the GHashTable container from glib, and I'm seeing some strange behavior in lookups. The problem boils down to the following:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GHashTable *h;
char val[]  = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O',0};

void f1()
{
   int k;
   scanf("%d", &k);
        g_hash_table_insert(h, &k, val);
}

void f2()
{
   int m;
   f1();
   scanf("%d", &m);
   gpointer *p = g_hash_table_lookup(h, &m);
   printf("%s\n", (const char*)p);
}

int main()
{
   h = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);
   f2();
   return 0;
}
```

In function `f2`, the result of `g_hash_table_lookup` is 0x00. However, if I call `f1` from main before calling `f2` and skip calling `f1` from `f2`, the code works as expected and prints "HELLO".

I think I'm missing something very basic here. How do I do hash table inserts and lookups correctly in glib?

Comment: Can you temporarily replace the `scanf` calls with a hardcoded integer?

Comment: I tried doing that, but the result is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe GLib `GHashTable` only takes keys that are pointers. It does not take integer keys. When you create the hash table with the g_int_hash key function, you need to fetch from it using pointers to gint objects, not just plain ints.  So instead of

```
g_hash_table_lookup(h, m)
```

try

```
g_hash_table_lookup(h, g_new(gint, 1))
```

See http://blog.sensecodons.com/2012/01/glib-ghashtable-and-gdirecthash.html

Comment: I just made an edit t the post, now insert is ` g_hash_table_insert(h, &k, val);` and lookup is `g_hash_table_lookup(h, &m);`. Still getting the same result though.

Comment: The variable k goes out of scope at the end of f1(), so it's address is no longer valid. You'll have to use the address of a persistently allocated int. You might also consider using g_direct_hash.

Comment: So, does this mean that if I want to look something up in a glib hashtable I have to use the same precise object that was used as the key when putting the element there?

Comment: I think I understand it now. Apparently glib does not keep the copy of the key in the hash table data structure, it only keeps the pointer to the key.

Comment: Depends on the hash function argument you pass, but generally, yes. Sounds like you really need g_direct_hash here. Note: the hashtable only keeps a pointer to the value as well as the key, so that too has to be persistent or copied.

Comment: Doing  g_hash_table_lookup(h, g_new(gint, 1)); will leak an int-pointer. You can set up the hashtable to automatically free the key and value that is used when inserting, but for lookup this would simply leak. Do GINT_TO_POINTER instead.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the conversion macro GINT_TO_POINTER, see here: https://developer.gnome.org/glib/2.34/glib-Type-Conversion-Macros.html

so:

```
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

GHashTable *h;
char val[]  = {'H', 'E', 'L', 'L', 'O',0};

void f1()
{
   int k;
   scanf("%d", &k);
   g_hash_table_insert(h, GINT_TO_POINTER(k), val);
}

void f2()
{
   int m;
   f1();
   scanf("%d", &m);
   gpointer *p = g_hash_table_lookup(h, GINT_TO_POINTER(m));
   printf("%s\n", (const char*)p);
}

int main()
{
   h = g_hash_table_new(g_int_hash, g_int_equal);
   f2();
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `GINT_TO_POINTER` for the key and `g_int_hash` / `g_int_equal` for the hash / lookup functions will segfault. Both `g_int_hash` and `g_int_euqal` will try to deref the pointer and it's not really a pointer (thanks to `GINT_TO_POINTER`). You've gotta use `g_direct_hash` / `g_direct_equal` in the call to `g_hash_table_new`.